# Android Service Get Package of Binder

Tags: android, android-service

Is there a way to find the package that is binding to a service on Android?

The service is using the Messenger IPC mechanism, and runs in it's own process. From what I can tell you can not get the package name from the `onBind` or the `handleMessage` methods.

I am trying to create a service that filters what applications can do what based on permissions, since the service is to provide a way to access a hardware device.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the loose coupling of service binding, it seems that you are right about not being able to get the binding package name as a `Service`. However, if:

- your permission scheme is fairly simple; and
- you are either building or have some say in the design of the `Service` consumer

you could take a look at defining a [custom app permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining) and setting the [`android:permission`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#prmsn) attribute of the `Service` to this permission, thus letting Android take care of the access control for you.

Something like adding:

```
<permission android:name="au.com.msbit.permission.CUSTOM_PERMISSION" />
```

as a child of the the `manifest` element and:

```
android:permission="au.com.msbit.permission.CUSTOM_PERMISSION"
```

as an attribute of the `service` element in you `AndroidManifest.xml`.